# Immutable structure in c#

Tags: c#, struct, immutability

I have code as follow:

```
struct Name
{

private int age;

public int Age
{
  get
  {
    return age;
  }
  set
  {
    age = Age;
  }
}
public Name(int a)
{
  age = a;
}

};

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Name myName = new Name(27);
      Console.WriteLine(myName.Age);
      myName.Age = 30;
      Console.WriteLine(myName.Age);
    }
  }
```

As you can see I am trying to change value of Age using my property. But i am getting still the same value which I pass when I am creating a object of struct Name. I know that struct are immutable in C#, but i thought i would bee able to change field in them. I am very confused. Could someone explain me what is going on?

Comment: Thanks for the example. It seems reproducible. However, it could possibly be more minimal by just demonstrating what the problem is. Maybe you want to create a copy of your project and then remove all code which is not relevant. E.g. I see no real value in providing FirstName, MiddleName and LastName if all implementations work the same way.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I've changed my code to be more readable.

Comment: You can have a mutable or immutable struct in C#, it's up entirely on how do you code in it. But generally it's agreed upon that [mutable structs are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441309/2557263).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structs in C# are not immutable by default. To mark a struct immutable, you should use the [readonly modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#readonly-struct) on the struct. The reason your properties aren't updating is that your syntax is wrong. You should use the [**value**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#properties-with-backing-fields) keyword to dereference the *value* provided to the setter.

```
public int Age
{
  get
  {
    return age;
  }
  set
  {
    age = value;          // <-- here
  }
}
```

Comment: @PiotrZdun: exactly. Since the `set()` "method" does not have a parameter for the new value, `value` does the magic.

Comment: Thank you. I am learning from Data Structures and Algorithms Using C# and I thing C# changed a little bit. Thanks for help.

Comment: I highly recommend the [C# in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/) to better understand the language. Keep learning friend.